# How to access Model attributes dynamically in a loop in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string-interpolation

My model class:

```
class item
  attr_accessor :item_name
  attr_accessor :item_url
  attr_accessor :item_label
  .
  . 
end
```

when I want to assign the value for this attributes.Insted of assigning one by one i.e`item.item_name="abc"`.

I want to put all the attributes in loop with hardcoded name and assign form some other source.

```
['item_url','item_url','item_label'].each do |attr|
   item.attr=values from some other source #error on this line
   #or
   item."#{attr}"=values from some other source #error on this line
end
```

Both of them not working. Any Suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
 item.send((attr + "="), values from some other source)
```

or:

```
hash = {}
['item_url','item_url','item_label'].each do |attr|
  hash[attr] = value
end
item.attributes = hash
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `send`:

```
item.send("#{attr}=", value)
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-send

Answer (score 1):

attr_accessor defines `#attr=` for each attribute given as setter method. So for example, you can use `#item_name=` to assign value to item_name. To invoke a method on an instance given the string or symbol of the method name, you call `__send__` on the instance.

```
['item_url','item_url','item_label'].each do |attr|
  item.__send__("#{attr}=", value)
end
```

`send` also works, but I prefer `__send__` as `send` is more likely to be overwritten by accident.

Comment: Thank you For the extra info @tyamagu2